# Magento 2: Filter Field with Date Issue

Tags: magento2, admin, filter, date, magento2.1.6

I have below code

```
$updatedAtFrom = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($updatedAt['orig_from']));
$updatedAtTo = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($updatedAt['orig_to']));
$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('DATE(main_table.updated_at)', array('from' => $updatedAtFrom,'to' => $updatedAtTo));
```

When I run query it displays

```
(`DATE(main_table`.`updated_at)` >= '2017-04-17' AND `DATE(main_table`.`updated_at)` <= '2017-04-17')
```

So it gives `#1054 - Unknown column 'DATE(main_table.updated_at)' in 'where clause'`

When I remove DATE then it works fine. I have that field as type timestamp. But I want to compare only Date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NOT TEST YET]
You can try with `Zend_Db_Expr`.

```
$queryExpr = new \Zend_Db_Expr("DATE(main_table.updated_at) >= '{$updatedAtFrom}' AND DATE(main_table.updated_at) <= '{$updatedAtTo}'");

$this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where($queryExpr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to format date in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format. Then use collection filter as follows.

```
$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('updated_at', ['lteq' => $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')])
    ->addFieldToFilter('updated_at', ['gteq' => $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
```

Where **$datetime** is object of **DateTime**.

Comment: I need to only compare with `DATE(updated_at)`. Need right syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Zend_Db_Expr.

```
$updatedAtFrom = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($updatedAt['orig_from']));
$updatedAtTo = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($updatedAt['orig_to']));
$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter(new \Zend_Db_Expr("DATE(main_table.updated_at)"), array('from' => $updatedAtFrom,'to' => $updatedAtTo));
```